# strcpy does not copy source string to dest

Tags: c

strcpy does not work for me.

When I execute code belows, it prints noting on my screen after my input with `EOF`.

And I tried use `gdb` to debug it, found out that `line` does not copy to `p`.

I am a new fish with c, and I stucked at this problem. Please help me.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int getline1(char *, int);

char *alloc(int);

void afree(char *);

int main(void)
{
    char *p, line[1000];
    int len;

    len = getline1(line, 1000);

    p = alloc(len);

    line[len - 1] = '\0';
    strcpy(p, line);
    printf("%s\n", p);
    return 0;
}

/* getline: get line into s, return length */
int getline1 (char *s, int lim)
{
        int c, i;

        i = 0;
        while (--lim > 0 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                s[i++] = c;
        if (c == '\n')
                s[i++] = c;
        *s = '\0';
        return i;
}

#define ALLOCSIZE   10000   /* size of available space */

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];    /* storage for alloc */
static char *allocp = allocbuf; /* next free position */

char *alloc(int n)      /* return pointer to n characters */
{
    if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n) {
        /* it fits */
        allocp += n;
        return allocp - n;  /* old p */ 
    } else {    /* not enough room */
        return 0;
    }
}

void afree(char *p) /* free storage pinted to by p */
{
    if (p >= allocbuf && p < allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE)
        allocp = p;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show an example of input and expectd output vs actual output.

Comment: Did you check if `getline1` works correctly?

Comment: change `*s = '\0';` to `s[i] = '\0';`

Comment: @shanechiu conclusion. Write a function, test it, and when it works then proceed. Learn to use how to use your debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is made in the getline1() function: Just before the return statement you have "*s = '\0';" which actually sets s[0] to NUL.  So you return always an empty string, because the very first byte is set to '\0'.